# sql server - An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'dbo'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i'm getting the above error when i try and run any alter table type script, even an add column script returns this error eg:

```
alter table up_retail add StockGroupID int null
```

running the above will return the above error, i have tried restarting sql, restore ansi settings etc, does anyone have any advice on what might be causing this?

**UPDATE:**
when i try and drop constraints as per

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ZSeeAlso] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_ZSeeAlso_Performers]
```

i get this:

> Incorrect syntax near 'dbo'.

again, any ideas what would cause this?

** UPDATE 2 **
for everyone checking this is the only thing in my query window, here is my ssms:

[image]

Comment: Is this the full script?

Comment: for this part, yes, its the line that is causing me issues

Comment: I asked because I could not recreate the error.  Is it possible an earlier section of your script isn't correctly terminated and therefore SQL is reading this as part of that query?  Can you run just that statement in isolation?

Comment: i cant run it in isolation, i could run alter scripts yesterday but today it won't seem to let me and i have no idea how or why, was wondering if anyone new of a sql setting that might have changed

Comment: show us your entire script

Comment: the alter table is my entire script

Comment: What do you mean you can run it in isolation but now it doesn't work? The error message you are getting is not possible from the code you posted. At one point you said this is part of your script, but then you said it is the entire script.

Comment: yesterday i could run that single line of code, today i try and run it, i get this error, it was part of a script but i took this line out and tried to run it by itself, as this was causing an error, so that's why i said this is my whole script, the rest of it is not being run

Comment: Is it possible that your database or server has a badly written (e.g. untested up until now) [DDL Trigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175941.aspx)?

Comment: i've had a look, but cant see anything untoward with the DDL stuff, its just off that it worked yesterday and now isnt working today when nothing to my knowledge has changed, might have to re-install it

Comment: are you running it from management studio?

Comment: yes, sql server 2012

Comment: have also tried it from the command prompt, get the same error

Comment: and the `alter table up_retail add StockGroupID int null` is the only text in your white empty query window?

Comment: yes its the only statement, i've added a pic to the main text

Comment: You have the word column in this pic..

Comment: Does up_detail exist in Master?
Perhaps you need to....

Use ThisDB
GO

alter table up_retail add StockGroupID int null

Comment: i do have the word column as it moans about a syntax error if i don't , another weird quirk of whatever this error is about, correct, the table doesnt exist in the master db but it doesnt even get that far

Comment: In which db does the table exist in?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is okey , try to `Use YourDB`  that contains the table `up_retail` **Not** `Master` like this :

```
Use YourDB

Alter Table up_retail Add StockGroupID int null

Go
```

Comment: @DanSolo Good Lock.

Answer (score 0):

after trying everything i can think and that, that was suggested in here, i  basically ended up re-installing sql and that seems to have fixed. it looks like the syntax engine or sql itself became corrupt for some reason

thanks all for the suggestions